# Почему при загрузке картинки вылезают ошибки?

Tags: php, mysql

При загрузке картинки вылезает куча ошибок, а в бд записывается NULL

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in product.php on line 95

Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/Снимок экрана 2021-09-01 в 19.13.33.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in product.php on line 58

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php1x6JkH" to "images/Снимок экрана 2021-09-01 в 19.13.33.png" in product.php on line 58

```
Form.php

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <p><label for="title">Название товара</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="title" required name="title">
    </p>
    <p><label for="price">Цена товара</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="price" name="price">
    </p>
    <p><label for="description">Описание товара</label><br>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p><label for="category">Категория товара</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="category" name="category">
    </p>
    <p><label for="image">Картинка товара</label><br>
        <input id="image" type="file" name="image">
    </p><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
    <p><label for="active">Активен</label>
        <input id="active" value="1" name="active" type="checkbox">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Добавить товар">

</form>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["title"])){
        $new_product = new Product($_POST["title"]);
        $new_product->setPrice($_POST["price"]);
        $new_product->setDescription($_POST["description"]);
        $new_product->setCategory($_POST["category"]);
        $new_product->setImage($_FILES["image"]);
        $new_product->setActive($_POST["active"]);
        $new_product->addProduct();
    }
}
?>
```

```
Product.php

class Product{
    public $title;
    private $price;
    private $description;
    private $category;
    private $image;
    private $active;

    private $link;
    private $target_path = "images/";


    public function __construct($title){
        $this->title = $title;

        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "testdb");
    }

    public function setPrice($price){
        if($price == ""){
            $this->price = 0;
        }
        else{
            $this->price = $price;
        }
    }

    public function setDescription($description){
        if($description == ""){
            $this->description = '';
        }
        else{
            $this->description = $description;
        }
    }

    public function setCategory($category){
        if($category == ""){
            $this->category = '';
        }
        else{
            $this->category = $category;
        }
    }

    public function setImage($image){
        if($image == ''){
            $this->image = '';
        }
        else{
            if($this->is_valid_type($image['name'])){
                $this->target_path .= $image['name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $this->target_path)){
                    $this->image = $this->target_path;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function setActive($active){
        if($active==1){
            $this->active = 1;
        }
        else{
            $this->active = 0;
        }
    }

    public function addProduct(){
        $query = "INSERT INTO products (title, price, description, category, image, active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sisssi", $this->title, $this->price, $this->description, $this->category, $this->image, $this->active);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function deleteProduct($id){
        $query = "DELETE product WHERE id=?";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    private function is_valid_type($filename){
        $valid_types = array("jpeg", "png", "jpg", "svg");
        $file_type = end(explode(".", $filename));
        if (in_array($file_type, $valid_types)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что непонятно во фразе "Only variables should be passed by reference"? тем более что сразу поясняется, что именно не так...

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: "Все равно выдает ошибку" --- А что ты исправил для устранения ошибки?

Comment: Поправил код, чтобы он не выдавал ошибку "Only variables should be passed by reference". Эта ошибка пропала, но остались другие

Comment: Осталась ошибка 'Undefined array key "active" in'

Answer (score 0):

У вас некорректный `$target_path`, используйте полный путь к папке для загрузки.

Comment: Я уже исправил это. У меня осталась ошибка 'Undefined array key "active" in'

Comment: не отмеченный (unchecked) checkbox не передает value и поэтому в массиве $_POST нет ключа active и тогда в строке ```$new_product->setActive($_POST["active"]);``` будет такая ошибка

Comment: Понял, спасибо!